# What is the best practice for passing filename strings to a funciton in C++?

Tags: c++, function, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm writing an c++ class that needs to reference either English or French words sorted by syllable count. The formatted dictionary files are named based on their language, and after they are read in, the English and French functions in the class share the same logic.

```
//Files needed for French
const char sSingleSyllablePath[] = "FR-SGL.txt";
const char sDoubleSyllablePath[] = "FR-DBL.txt";
const char sTripleSyllablePath[] = "FR-TRI.txt";
//...
```

The arrays need to have the same name, but reference different files:

```
//Files needed for English
const char sSingleSyllablePath[] = "EN-SGL.txt";
const char sDoubleSyllablePath[] = "EN-DBL.txt";
const char sTripleSyllablePath[] = "EN-TRI.txt";
//...
```

The directory containing all of the files is passed to the constructor, then the filename strings are referenced in an initialization function.

What is the best way to call this with the correct filename assignments? Having two separate classes with the same code but different names would be easy but does not seem efficient. Since there are many required files, it also does not seem right to have a huge list of parameters in the constructor.

Comment: Build a *locale* object that links to a language-dependent string table.

Comment: Can't you "construct" the file name in a single function given the language and sillable number?

Answer (score 1):

you can just use std::string:

```
const std::string sSingleSyllablePath = "-SGL.txt";
const std::string sDoubleSyllablePath = "-DBL.txt";
const std::string sTripleSyllablePath = "-TRI.txt";
```

then you have to define a function like this:

```
std::string getLocalized(const std::string &loc, const std::string &filename)
{
  return loc + filename;
}
```

this is a separate function just because - what if you need to do some stuff before create localized filename.

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a constant pointer to constant data:

```
void My_Function(char const * const p_text);
```

This doesn't create a new variable, unlike using `std::string`.

BTW, you may want to consider declaring the strings as `static`.  I've found that the `static` keyword allows compilers to emit code that directly accesses the strings (rather than copying them).  You can still pass a pointer to a static string.